# FiscalWeek Number in python

Tags: python, fiscal

I have a requirement to get the FiscalWeek Number. My companies Fiscal Year start on July i.e FY22 is from July2021 to June2022. So the first week of July will be 1 , next week will be 2 etc. Not able to get Python code for the same
Got the Fiscal Quarter using the below code

dataset['As Quarter'] = dataset['Date'].dt.to_period('Q-JUN')

dataset['Fiscal Year'] = dataset['As Quarter'].dt.qyear

and

dataset['Fiscal Year Range'] = dataset['Date'].dt.to_period('Q-JUN').dt.qyear.apply(lambda x: str(x-1) + "-" + str(x))

But not able to get the code for Week Number

Comment: Please show us what did you try so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on python 3.9 you can use this code:

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2021, 11, 26).isocalendar().week
```

Output:

```
47
```

Here the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar

Then to get your fiscal week, just use a timedelta between the date tested and your fiscal start date.